# How do a properly prediction of negative values in regression problem with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression, activation-function

I am trying to adopt a standard Boston housing problem for my dataset, the difference is I have negative values in the dataset and want to predict negative values in the output.

As I read in StackOverflow to predict negative values I should use a than activation function on the output layer. Also, I understand that I should normalize my dataset to the -1,1 range.

So I have two questions.
I have two variants of code.

1. Is my first variant of code correct? I have not found any public datasets with negative numbers to check and don't know how to be sure it works well.
2. In the second variant my NN predicts a value like "0.9", but my dataset value is like "24". I assume it because there is no proper normalization in this code. Please advise me on how to implement normalization.

I have a poor experience in Keras and not so strong skills in Python, so I just try to assemble a piece of code from different places.

First code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

#read in training data
train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', index_col='ID')
train_df.head()

target = 'medv'

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1)) ## tut byl 0,1
scaled_train = scaler.fit_transform(train_df)

# Print out the adjustment that the scaler applied to the total_earnings column of data
print("Note: median values were scaled by multiplying by {:.10f} and adding {:.6f}".format(scaler.scale_[13], scaler.min_[13]))
multiplied_by = scaler.scale_[13]
added = scaler.min_[13]

scaled_train_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_train, columns=train_df.columns.values)

#build our model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh')) #tut nichego

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

X = scaled_train_df.drop(target, axis=1).values
Y = scaled_train_df[[target]].values

# Train the model
model.fit(
    X[10:],
    Y[10:],
    epochs=100,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2
)

#inference
prediction = model.predict(X[:4])
y_0 = prediction[0][0]
print('Prediction with scaling - {}',format(y_0))
y_0 -= added
y_0 /= multiplied_by
print("Housing Price Prediction  - ${}".format(y_0))



Prediction with scaling - {} -0.1745799034833908
Housing Price Prediction  - $23.571952171623707
```

Second variant of code:

```
# Regression Example With Boston Dataset: Standardized and Larger
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy
# load dataset
dataframe = read_csv("housing.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:13]
Y = dataset[:,13]
# define the model
def larger_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
# evaluate model with standardized dataset
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=larger_model, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=1)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Larger: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

pipeline.fit(X, Y)
#prediction = pipeline.predict(numpy.array([[0.0273, 0., 7.07, 0., 0.469, 6.421, 78.9, 4.9671, 2., 242., 17.8, 396.9, 9.14]]))
prediction = pipeline.predict(numpy.array([[0.7258, 0., 8.14, 0., 0.538, 5.727, 69.5, 3.7965, 4., 307., 21.0, 390.95, 11.28]]))
print(prediction)
```

Result:

```
......
......
102/102 [==============================] - 0s 927us/step - loss: 548.0819
Epoch 50/50
102/102 [==============================] - 0s 912us/step - loss: 548.0818
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step

0.99998754
```

[Link to train.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/Machine-Learning-Operationalization/master/samples/spark/tutorials/datasets/housing.csv)

[Link to housing.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/housing.data)

Answer (score 0):

Here in the final output layer you are using tanh activation that is tha problem.tanh activation function will provide the output from -1 to +1 you can try linear activation function instead of tanh

Comment: by default there was model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
now i put
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))

as i know its the same.
For boston housing dataset it working like a charm, but will it works with negative values prediction?

Comment: yeah did you tried that..Is it is giving the expected output

Comment: forcurrent positive dataset it works good.
real 18.20, predicted 16.705591

but dunno how it will be for negative

Comment: what dataset is you are using is it is public dataset means give the link

Comment: could you advice any public datasets to play, with negative values ang regression problem?

Comment: now on what dataset you are working for the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230842/discussion-between-yid-and-navy).